# How can I view the Tables structure in sqlite Manager add-on on Firefox?

Tags: ios, sqlite, swift2, fmdb

I am creating a Database called `Reminder.sqlite` via `Sqlite Manager` add-on in firefox, after creating I am importing it to my iOS Application, the problem is that records are saved in database table but when I run a Select query in Sqlite manager no records are displayed any suggestions why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have add database file into project and remove database file from document directory.
because old file is exist in document director, your new file with same name cannot be overwrite old one.(according to approach, if we use in code)
It may help you.

Comment: i am opening the same database which i used in my project in sqlite manager by exporting it

Comment: by connecting database

Comment: Try this: 
If your running your application on Simulator, Uninstall your Application from it and reset it.
otherwise remove your application from your device.